# How can I easily test sound (speakers and Mic) on my ipad?

Tags: ipad, microphone, speakers

I do a lot of webinars and sometimes ipads viewing the webinar have sound problems.

I'm looking for a really easy way for them to test their speakers and mic.
(Speakers are relatively easy to test, and often very commonly used, so it's more obvious (to them) if they aren't working.)  But would be good to test both at the same time.

Thanks!

Comment: What you're asking for would only test the physical hardware, which is unlikely to be causing the sound problems in your webinar.  If that is the case then some quick web searches would have returned a number of ways to exercise the Mic and speakers.  If your goal is to understand why the audio is bad on an iPad then you need to provide more details.

Comment: @iWill  It is never a bad thing to have a way to test whether the hardware works or not.  Many times I have seen techs spend hours trying to solve a problem like not getting video on Skype by diagnosing all sorts of software and connectivity issues when it was the webcam that was bad.

Comment: @Allan I'm not suggesting that it isn't useful to test the hardware just the answer seems easy to find with very basic web searches.

Answer (score 2):

Take a video of anything (yourself, your pets, traffic, etc.)  and while recording, say something.  Replay the video.  If you hear the sound you are supposed to, it works.

This has the benefits of testing both at the same time and ruling out hardware issues should you run into difficulties during the webinar.